# Recover LVM to single drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, lvm

### The situation

I have a volume group that spans four 1TB drives with six logical volumes. Three drives have full-drive physical volumes (no partitions), while the fourth drive contains /boot and a partition dedicated to the final physical volume.

One drive *may* be damaged and require recovery, however that is outside the scope of the question. I'm just explaining my situation for context. As soon as I suspected an issue, I forced shut-down the computer and purchased a new 5TB drive. My recovery computer (I don't trust the original computer, it may have been a motherboard failure) doesn't have enough sata slots. The 5TB recovery target occupies one slot, one of the four 1TB recovery source drives occupies another, and I've booted a full ubuntu OS via USB.

In case a drive is damaged, I would like to use ddrescue to copy data.

### The Question

How can I copy my four physical volumes to a single hard drive, with only one volume available at a time, and with some physical volumes being full-disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create partitions of size 1Gb on new drive (use GPT because of big disk), and copy each PV to its partition (it doesn't matter if original was using full drive - you just need to take care to provide enough space, and then do `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb3` for example).

When all partions/disks are copied as partitions on new drive, simply restarting lvm (or rebooting) will rescan all partitions on new disk, and provide you with all the PVs.